# Laravel 5 - How to use $this->app->when()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Reading about laravel [bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding),I understand `$this->app->bind`,`$this->app->singleton` and `$this->app->instance` because they are almost the same.

But `$this->app->when` is a little bit tricky for me.

In laravel example

```
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')
          ->needs('$variableName')
          ->give($value);
```

In my understanding it injects some primitive value and the `App\Http\Controllers\UserController` is the alias of the object that will be binded.But where is the object?

Can anyone explain? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9):

Contextual binding does not work on variable names, but on types. It is used to provide different implementations for interfaces to consuming classes or functions, depending on the context. In fact, you can actually read the method calls and it does exactly what you'd expect. To elaborate on this, I'll take the example of the documentation and adapt it slightly:

```
$this->app->when(Worker::class)
          ->needs(Money::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new Dollar();
          });

$this->app->when(Boss::class)
          ->needs(Money::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new Cheque();
          });
```

In this example, `Money` is an interface and `Dollar` as well as `Cheque` are implementations of the interface. The example literally means that if you typehint `Money` on a `Worker` class, it will resolve to an instance of `Dollar` while it will resolve to `Cheque` on a `Boss` class. To illustrate, here the implementations and the results:

```
interface Money
{
    public function getAmount();
}

class Dollar implements Money
{
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Cheque implements Money
{
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return 100000;
    }
}
```

And now we typehint the `Money` interface to see what we'll get:

```
class Worker
{
    public function __construct(Money $money)
    {
        echo $money->getAmount(); // prints '1'
    }
}

class Boss
{
    public function __construct(Money $money)
    {
        echo $money->getAmount(); // prints '100000'
    }
}
```

Comment: nice addition :) I have referenced it in my answer because we both focus on a different usage of the binding (Contextual binding vs primitive binding)

Answer (score 2):

It means that if a class of `UserController` is instantiated and it needs a variable with the name `$variableName` Larvel will automatically resolve this variable with the given value and you don't have to provide it.

For example:

```
$value = "Sven"
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')
          ->needs('$userName')
          ->give($value);
```

This would insert the value 'Sven' into the UserController whenever it needs the variable with the name `$userName`

In other words, if you had a function like `public function __construct(Request $request)` Laravel knows what to insert because it knows that a `Request` object is expected. When you use a function like `public function __construct($name)` Laravel has no clue what to insert here, essentially you tell Laravel how to resolve this variable with the bindings.

This is an example of **primitive binding**, for Contextual binding see the answer of @Namoshek

Comment: In my understanding, the first parameter of when() which is **App\Http\Controllers\UserController** is only an identifier. Im expecting a second parameter which is the acutal object/class.

Comment: @ktaro, yes that is correct. Laravel will use this identifier to register the signature of this class so it can take action (insert the variable) when something is done with this class

Comment: @ktaro, I also added more context to the answer. I hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Thanks @Sven. Im expecting like this **$this->app->instance('HelpSpot\API', $api)**.First param is identifer,second param is the object. Do you mean the identifier **App\Http\Controllers\UserController** is also the object?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I don't think your last addition is what contextual binding is all about. It is not about resolving variable names, but types - depending on the context. Personally, I think the example in the documentation is very good and should give you a good idea what it stands for.

Comment: @Namoshek, that is true but I considered this to be more relevant in the case of the OP since the binding of different interfaces goes a step further I thought this example might be easier to understand and from that the usage of Contextualbinding could be understood based on the documentation :)

Comment: @ktaro in the case of `instance()` the second argument is an instantiated class (object) where with `when()` it is just an identifier of the class to which the resolver needs to be bound

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone finds this thread, trying to achieve contextual binding on an app()->make() or similar situation:

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

class FooBar {

    public function doSomething(): void
    {
       //...do your thing
       $this->getFooObject();
    }

    private function getFooObject(): FooAbstract 
    {
        $class = FooAbstract::class;
        $buildStack = static::class;

        app()->beforeResolving(
                $class,
                Closure::bind(
                    function () use ($buildStack) {
                        $this->buildStack[] = $buildStack;
                    },
                    app(),
                    Container::class,
                )
           );

        return app($class);
    }
}
```

In the above example laravel's app container is bind as `$this` to this closure. Since the `buildStack` property, that's used to identify the object that "needs" the object that is being created, is protected, we have access to it, and we can add the classname to the stack.

for example: if `$buildStack = Bar::class`; you can do the following

```
app()->when(FooBar::class)->needs(FooAbstract::class)->give(FooImplementation::class);
```

Comment: it's weird, but it works. thanks.